# retrieve carrierwave file uploaded to Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, amazon-s3, carrierwave

Using Rails 3.2, carrier wave, and recently switched to store on Amazon S3. My setup and uploads are all working fine.
1. I have image_uploader.rb to upload and store images.  Displaying them all works fine
2. I have file_uploader.rb to upload and store files.  I've even taken it a step further to upload ZIP files and extract a version so that both the ZIP file and TXT files are stored in the correct place on S3.
My problem is I run a method on the TXT file.  In the past, I used `storage :file`
With that I was able to:

```
Dir.chdir("public/uploads/")
import_file = Dir['*.TXT'].first
f = File.new(import_file)
```

Now, that I'm using `storage :fog`  I can't get seem to retrieve/File.new/Open the file.
I see the file with the usual commands:

```
@upload1.team_file                      # stored file
@upload1.team_file.url                  # url
@upload1.team_file_url(:data_file).to_s # version created
```

I've been pouring through all kinds of very limited leads on retrieving and/or opening the file, but everything I try seems to return errors, such as:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - https://teamfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/data_files…
```

Thoughts on the difference here of retrieving and USING a file from AmazonS3?  Thanks!

Comment: get this value and try putting in a browser - `@upload1.team_file.url` , it is possible you are getting an access error?

Comment: Nice lead house9. As I mentioned, I upload the ZIP file and then extract the text file with uniq ext .abc   But, from browser I noticed the errors for the MAIN file and the download for the VERSION file.  From S3 Console Metadata Key: content type, Value: application/ZIP     The Value needs to be text/abc  which is unique extension.  Once I set that, my method could open the file with the following:           f = open(self.team_file_url(:data_file))    Now the trick is to figure out how to adjust the Metadata properly on the extracted file, without having to manually set it every time!!??

Answer (score 3):

Pulling from multiple threads, APIs, etc. I'm answering my own question with what I've found. I welcome any corrections or improvements:

To retrieve carrierwave files uploaded to AmazonS3, you have to understand that `open(@upload.file_url)` or `File.open(@upload.file_url)` does NOT open the file, it only opens the PATH to the file. (ref: [Ruby OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) )
I use:   `open_uri_url = open(@upload.file_url)`

You then have to find the specific file in that path that you want.  For me, I then find a ZIP file that was uploaded to AmazonS3 and Extract the specific file within the ZIP file that I want with a unique *.ABC extension:

```
zip_content_file = Zip::File.open(open_uri_url).map{|content| content if content.to_s.split('.').last == "ABC"}.compact.first
```

Now, from here, where to extract to??  I create a unique directory in the Rails tmp directory to extract the file to, use it and then delete the directory:

```
tmp_directory = "tmp/extracts/#{@upload.parent_id}/"
FileUtils.mkdir_p(tmp_directory) unless File.directory?(tmp_directory)
extract = zip_content_file.extract(tmp_directory + content_file.to_s)
```

Now with found from the AmazonS3 stored ZIP file and extracted, I can open, read, etc:

```
f = File.new(tmp_directory + extract.to_s)
```

I hope this helps with Carrierwave, AmazonS3, ZIP files and using them once uploaded.